# Socket io get is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I'm using Sails JS and i tried to use socket IO librarie.

As it is explained in Sails JS documentation : http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets

I create a controller with this code:

```
index: function(req, res) {

    var param = req.param('msg');

    console.log("PARAM : ", param); // For display the message in terminal

    // Send a JSON response
    return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: param
    });
},
```

And in my template (i use swig JS template engine) :

For include socket io library :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And in JavaScript code :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

socket.get('/echo', {
    message: 'hi there!'
}, function(response) {
    console.log ('response : ', response);
});
```

And i've this error : undefined is not a function on socket.get('/echo' ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Make sure you have added `sails.io.js` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/sails.io.js"></script>` as well. Since `Socket.prototype.get` is defined in this file.

Comment: @miceli: If this answered your question, you might like to mark it as such by clicking the answer's check-mark. If you liked the question you also are free to upvote it.